# Merging two DataFrames (CSV files) with different dates using Python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, merge

I would like to know how can I proceed in order to concatenate two csv files, here is the composition of this two files:

- The first one contains some datas related to water chemical parameters, these measurements are taken in different dates.
- The second one shows the different flow values of waste water, during a certain period of time.

The problem is that I am looking to assign each value of the second file (Flow values) to the right row in the first file (water chemical parameters) in such a way that the flow and the other chemical parameters are measured in the same moments.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: a sample of both files would be appreciated in order to give you a glimpse of functional code

Comment: Can you post some sample data and code that you might have used.

Answer (score 0):

The first file is smth like:

Timestamp ;       Flow1 ;    Flow 2
2017/02/17 00:05 ; 540 ;       0 
2017/02/17 00:10 ; 535 ;       0 
2017/02/17 00:15 ; 543 ;       0 
2017/02/17 00:20 ; 539 ;       0

CSV file #2:

Timestamp ; DOC ; Temperatute ; UV254; 
2017/02/17 00:14 ; 668.9 ; 15,13 ; 239,23 
2017/02/17 00:15 ; 669,46 ; 15,14 ; 239,31 
2017/02/17 00:19 ; 668 ; 15,13 ; 239,43 
2017/02/17 00:20 ; 669,9 ; 15,14 ; 239,01

he output file is supposed to be like : 
                                                                    Timestamp      ;  DOC  ;   Temperatute  ; UV254  ;   Flow1 ;    Flow2                                                   2017/02/17 00:15  ; 669,46 ; 15,14   ;     239,31  ;    543    ;       0
2017/02/17 00:20  ; 669,9   ; 15,14   ;     239,01  ;    539   ;       0